¿Cómo eliminar los ultimos caracteres de una cadena?
Tengo el siguiente marco de datos:
        Id      SleepDay
       <dbl>    <chr>
1   1503960366  4/12/2016 12:00:00 AM       
2   1503960366  4/13/2016 12:00:00 AM

Quiero eliminar de la cadena 4/12/2016 12:00:00 AM
que me quede de esta forma solo la cadena fecha: 4/12/2016 para luego convertirlo a tipo date. Lo que intento hacer es extraer desde la posición 1 hasta que consiga el primer espacio y restarle 1 posición:
sleep_Day <- mutate(sleep_Day, SleepDay = substring(sleep_Day$SleepDay,1," ")) 

me trae NA

Podés utilizar el paquete lubridate para leer la fecha como una fecha en formato fecha + horas:minutos:segundos y luego usar la acostumbrada as.Date para solo extraer la fecha:
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

SleepDay %>% 
   mutate(Fecha = mdy_hms(SleepDay) %>% as.Date)
# A tibble: 2 × 3
          Id SleepDay              Fecha     
       <dbl> <chr>                 <date>    
1 1503960366 4/12/2016 12:00:00 AM 2016-04-12
2 1503960366 4/13/2016 12:00:00 AM 2016-04-13

Si querés usar la fuerza bruta, acá te dejo una alternativa con una expresión regular:
SleepDay %>% 
  mutate(Fecha = as.Date(sub("(\\d+/\\d+/\\d+).*", "\\1", SleepDay), format = "%m/%d/%Y") )
# A tibble: 2 × 3
          Id SleepDay              Fecha     
       <dbl> <chr>                 <date>    
1 1503960366 4/12/2016 12:00:00 AM 2016-04-12
2 1503960366 4/13/2016 12:00:00 AM 2016-04-13


Ya que posiblemente estes usando tidyverse puedes hacer lo siguiente:
sleep_Day %>% 
  separate(SleepDay, sep = ' ', into="Fecha")

          Id     Fecha
1 1503960366 4/12/2016
2 1503960366 4/13/2016
Aviso:
Expected 1 pieces. Additional pieces discarded in 2 rows [1,
2]. 

separate() divide una columna en múltiples por ciero delimitador, el warning es por que ignoramos las dos columnas adicionales que por cierto no las necesitamos.
Otra manera usando R base sería usando strsplit junto con lapply para quedarnos con la primer columna luego de la separación:
sleep_Day$Fecha <- lapply(strsplit(sleep_Day$SleepDay, ' '), `[[`, 1)

Por último, si el formato es consistente en todas las filas, podrías intentar convertir directamente a una fecha:
sleep_Day$Fecha <- as.Date(sleep_Day$SleepDay, "%m/%d/%Y")

